AlpineJS aynchronous data loading
I'm looking into AlpineJS for the first time and I'm trying to load some data into the x-data attribute.
I have something like
<body x-data="data">
...

in my HTML. Inside data I store all the data and functions I use later (it's a very simple SPA)
document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
  Alpine.data('data', () => ({
    foo: 1,
    bar: 2,
    ...
  }));
}

Everything works fine until all the variables are synchronous, but now I need to assign to one variable some data I get asynchronously from the DB.
I tried with something simple like
document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
  Alpine.data('data', async () => ({
    foo: 1,
    bar: await getData(),
    ...
  }));
}

which unfortunately does not work. I get a Uncaught ReferenceError: VARIABLE_NAME is not defined for each variable inside data.
How can I solve this issue? There is a standard way to handle situations like this one?

You can assign the async data in the init() method, and remove the async from the main data() function:
document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {

    Alpine.data("data", () => ({

        foo: 1,
        bar: null,

        init: async function () {

            this.bar = await this.getData();
        },

        getData: async function () {

            return Promise.resolve("abc");
        }
    }));
});


I accepted TUPKAP's answer as the solution. Looking into the Alpine's documentation I've found the topic here, if anyone needs more details.
On the documentation it's explained with a slightly different syntax, in my case it would be something like
Alpine.data('data', () => ({
        foo: 1,
        bar: null,
        async init () {
            this.bar = await getData();
        }
    })
};

They do exactly the same thing, I just find this syntax prettier.
